# Xamarin.Forms: Best way to catch click on button when there are objects on top (like a label and another image)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

in my app, I have the following layout:[image]

Its a grapcic, ontop is a label, and ontop is another graphic (also with another label). Now I still want people to be able to click the button. This already caused issued which the label onto. If youd click on the label instead of the button behind, nothing would happen. I got around this issue by simply adding two click handler: one on to the button and one onto the label. This was at least a workaround. But now I am faced with a greater issue:

You can see those layouts beeing on top of each other. As of now, it is impossible to click the button, because there are two grids stapled ontop of eacher (one containing the button, one containing the notify).

Only when I remove the notify is it possible to click the button again. But this ofc is no option. How can I make the button in background be clickable, even though there are things on top?

THis is the xaml:

```
<!--Grid for Button-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ImageButton
                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     x:Name="btn_mymatches_mainmenu"
                     Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>
            <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontFamily="arial"
                    TextColor="#272727"
                    Text="Meine Matches" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        </Grid>

        <!--Top Level Grid for Notifybutton-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Source="img_notify.png" />
            <Label
                    x:Name="label_notify_nr"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    FontSize="16"
                    FontFamily="arial"
                    TextColor="#ffff"
                    Text="1" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        </Grid>
```

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Because you two button in the same cell , so the notify button will cover all of the space of Grid .

In your case, it would be better to use **AbsoluteLayout**

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <AbsoluteLayout  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,.50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Frame Padding="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30">

                        <Button Text="11111" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

                    </Frame>


                </Grid>
            </Frame>

            <Frame   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".8,-.2,50,50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"   BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30">

                <Button Text="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"  BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White"/>

            </Frame>



        </AbsoluteLayout>



    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, i get the issue, but the problem is that with your logic, the notify button would sit on different positions depending on the phone you use, right? and i want it to be on the same spot - this i achieved by using the percentages "*" in the grids.

Comment: You could test my solution .